# Why does weight painting this skeleton with reverse kinematics rotate the vertex around the bone

Tags: weight-painting

I have a skeleton that I added reverse kinematics to because I have no idea what I'm doing, I watched a tutorial, and it seemed like a good idea. I needed to rotate the bone position so that the knee was bending correctly, so I added a rotation to it.

Presently, When I try to weight paint any of the upper leg vertices, they rotate inward 90 degrees. It seems that the bone rotation is being applied to the weight painting. How do I keep it so that the Knee still bends correctly, but the weight painting doesn't distort the vertices like this?
See a gif below, and the .blend file.

Thanks in advance!

[image: Weight painting vertex rotation]

[image]

Comment: Just a tip for future reference, but using [our non-official upload site](http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com) is generally preferred, as it has some nice features. :) I edited this in for you.

Comment: Thank you for the tip. I'll try to keep this in mind for future posts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go into the armature pose mode, select every thing with <kbd>A</kbd> then press <kbd>Ctrl + A</kbd> and "apply pose at rest pose".

Your bone constraints moved the bones in pose mode a little so you need to apply  their new transforms as the official "rest pose"
[image]

Comment: Thank you, this was very helpful for me. I appreciate the quick video as well.

Comment: no problem, I learned how to make a .gif here: http://meta.blender.stackexchange.com/questions/963/what-is-the-process-for-creating-gifs-for-questions-and-answers/1056  and just finished reading the chapter on rigging https://www.blender.org/manual/fr/rigging/index.html